# Generation of array of size 10^6 in C

Tags: c

I am testing the sorting techniques (Mergesort, Quicksort,...so on) in 'C' experimentally for comparison of time. For this purpose, I am generating an array of large sizes up to 10^8 randomly as shown in the code below. But this piece of code is working for the generation of size up to 10^5. If this limit exceeds the compiler stops working and displays a dialogue box "a.exe has stopped working".

Please help me out with this problem.
Thanks

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    long long int sz;
    printf("Enter the size of array::");
   scanf("%lld",&sz);

   array_generate(sz);
}


long long int array_generate(long long int sz){
    
   
   long long int randArray[sz];
   long long int i;
   for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
     randArray[i]=rand()%1000; //Generate number between 0 to 1000
}
```

Comment: That must be a variable-length array, which might be allocated on the stack, which seemingly isn't large enough for that in your case. Try either allocating with `malloc()`, or just not using such large sizes of array and/or element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is creating very large arrays as local variables.  Locals typically reside on the stack which is limited in size, so by defining such a large local array you are overflowing the stack, causing your program to crash.

Use `malloc` instead to dynamically allocate memory on the heap which is much larger.

```
long long int *randArray = malloc(sz * sizeof *randArray);
```

Comment: And use free() when you're done with it !

Answer (score 0):

As @dbush pointed out, you can't dynamically allocate such large arrays on the stack. You must use the heap instead.

As a general advise I would say never write something like that unless you really know what you're doing :

```c
int array[dynamic_size];
```

Instead use a fixed size array like so :

```c
#define FIXED_SIZE 200
[...]
int array[FIXED_SIZE];
// or int array[200];
```

Or use [malloc (3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

Regarding your code, what is usually done in C is that the caller allocates memory and passes its pointer to the function initializing it. So your main would look like that :

```c
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    long long int sz;
    printf("Enter the size of array::");
    scanf("%lld",&sz);

    // "sizeof *array" is the same as "sizeof(long long int)" but better because if you change the type of your array later, you won't have to change it twice (better from a maintainability POV)
    long long int *array = malloc(sz * sizeof *array); 

    array_generate(array, sz);
    array_process(array, sz);

    free(array);
    array = NULL; // not mandatory
}
```